# How to create Startup and Cleanup script for Visual Studio Test Project?

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, mstest

I'm using a Visual Studio Test project, am modifying the test config with deployment files, etc. (through the VS GUI) and now I need to write a Startup script for the test run.

I have no clue what language or file type or mechanism is used for these scripts. Need a tip.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Create a unit test in your test project.  In the unit test class, create methods with the `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` attributes.  They will be run before/after each test method.

Or, if you want to run before/after all test in that class, create static methods with `[ClassInitialize]` and `[ClassCleanup]` attributes.

Lastly, to run before/after all tests in the assembly, create static methods with `[AssemblyInitialize]` and `[AssemblyCleanup]` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it sent me in the right direction. From there I found `AssemblyInitialize` and `AssemblyCleanup` which is what I need in this case. Can you append these two Attributes to your answer for posterity...

Comment: Is there any advantage to using [ClassInitialize] instead of using the Class constructor?